# Generic type for Associative Enum

Tags: swift, enums

I have an `enum` like below:

```
public enum MyErrorEnum: LocalizedError {
    case FileNotFound(String = "Failed to find file.", file: String)

    public var errorDescription: String? {
        if let current = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first {
            let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: current.value);
            // Initial error description.
            let message = mirror.children.first?.value as? String
                ?? current.label ?? "Unknown-case";
            var context = "";
            // Iterate additional context.
            var i = 0;
            for associated in mirror.children {
                if i >= 1 {
                    if let text = associated.value as? String {
                        context += "\n  ";
                        if let label: String = associated.label {
                            context += "\(label): "
                        }
                        context += text;
                    }
                }
                i += 1;
            }
            return context.isEmpty ? message : (
                message + " {" + context + "\n}"
            );
        }
        return "\(self)";
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```swift
do {
    let path = "/path/to/file.txt";
    throw MyErrorEnum.FileNotFound(
        file: path
    );
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Failed to find file. {
  file: /path/to/file.txt
}
```

---

Now I would like to reuse `errorDescription` in any `enum` that implements `LocalizedError`, simply by moving `errorDescription`'s logic into extension.

### How should I change below to have working extension (for said matter)?

```
public enum MyErrorEnum: LocalizedError {
    case FileNotFound(String = "Failed to find file.", file: String)
}

extension DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE where Self: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        // ... imagine all above logic moved here.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper that would affect everything which implements `LocalizedError`, for example, I would like something like `extension RawRepresentable where RawValue == String, Self: LocalizedError {}` **but for associative-enums**.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, **Swift does not seem to provide Generic-Type for associative-enums yet** (while it has `RawRepresentable` for Raw-Value enums).

Solution; to not affect everything which implements `LocalizedError`, create your own protocol like:

```
public protocol LocalizedErrorEnum: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? { get }
}

extension LocalizedErrorEnum {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        if let current = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first {
            let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: current.value);
            // Initial error description.
            let message = mirror.children.first?.value as? String
                ?? current.label ?? "Unknown-case";
            var context = "";
            // Iterate additional context.
            var i = 0;
            for associated in mirror.children {
                if i >= 1 {
                    if let text = associated.value as? String {
                        context += "\n  ";
                        if let label: String = associated.label {
                            context += "\(label): "
                        }
                        context += text;
                    }
                }
                i += 1;
            }
            return context.isEmpty ? message : (
                message + " {" + context + "\n}"
            );
        }
        return "\(self)";
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public enum MyErrorEnum: LocalizedErrorEnum {
    case FileNotFound(String = "Failed to find file.", file: String)
}
```

Comment: FYI, semi colons are not needed, they are even discouraged, in swift.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't know about *discouraged*, but semi-colon is not required in `JavaScript` as well, but is *encouraged* in `JS` to prevent mistakes (the idea is, leaving the compile and/or uglify to respective tool, without removing semi-colon ourselves manually).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson but even in Swift, if someone by mistake adds `.doSomething()` instead of `doSomething()` to next line, if we don't have semi-colon, it toke them just one dot to make huge difference (I prefer to press one button extra, instead of debugging whole day).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I hope that explains it, if `Swift` did not like semi-colon, they should have prevent continuing on next-line entirely (instead of just making semi-colon optional like `JavaScript`).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Of course there can be other issues too; but having multiple methods with same name is pretty common, so let's hope they cause error. However, another reason is I want to find statement-end instantly by looking, without thinking and reading entire thing.